# Intellij IDEA - Actionscript Project - Cannot connect Debugger version of Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, intellij-idea, flash-builder

I installed flash player debugger and cannot able to debug the flash application.

And I got following message in console.

Waiting for Player to connect
Failed to connect; session timed out.
Ensure that:
  1. you compiled your Flash movie with debugging on, and
  2. you are running the Debugger version of the Flash Player.

Dont know how to fix.

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to debug? Pure SWF or HTML wrapper?

Comment: Are you using the standalone debugger version or the browser plugin? If you are using a browser, which one?

Comment: @Timofei  I am using pure swf. @bmleite I am new to intelllij IDEA and  don't know how to view the debugger version it trying to launch. But I installed both browser plug-ins.

Comment: Make sure, that your swf files are launching with the debugger version (in Windows go to Properties of any swf file and set the default application to open it). Or in IDEA: Tools -> Flex -> Create HTML Wrapper. And launch your application in html wrapper. You say, you've installed debugger plugin for browser, so it should work.

Comment: I found that issue is happens due to system default application. It is not the debug version of flash player. In Run/Debug Configuration, I cannot able to set Options for "Launch with" because it is diabled. I can able to set options for just before launching by selecting   Before Launch > show settings. I dont know it is intellij issue or mine.

Comment: You have to select one of the launch types: "HTML wrapper or swf file", "URL" or "Main class", then in "Launch with" option click on the button next to the input (the one with ellipses), on the popup select "Browser" and use the combobox to select the browser you want to use.

Comment: @bmleite eventhough i try to select those different options, "Launch with" option is not enabled. I think it is a bug in intellij,

Answer (score 4):

If you are using chrome, the default flash player is not the debug version. After installing the Debug version of the player. you must disable the default version in Chrome.

Open Chrome
Go to chrome://plugins

here you should see both versions of the shockwave player. Disable the first one or the one that is located here:
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\22.0.1229.94\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll

Now the debug version should be working in Chrome and should also work from Intellij if chrome is your default browser or set as the browser to open on debug.

Answer (score 4):

**Browser**

Don't use Chrome to debug your SWF as it contains a non-debugger version of Flash Player. So after installing the Flash Player debugger, use Firefox, for example and make it as default browser.

**SWF File**

Be sure that you compiled your file as a debug version. To do that, have a look to your project structure. Then on your module and build configuration. In the compiler options, you should be able to check the "Generate debuggable SWF" option.

[image]

**RUN/DEBUG Configuration**

Check in the What to launch option, you selected your swf via HTML Wrapper. Check also that you selected the right Flex SDK in the options panel:

[image]

**FINALLY**

Launch your debug configuration. Intellij will build your project, create an HTML wrapper and launch it in the default browser (Firefox).

Your SWF should then be debuggable. If it still does not connect to the debugger in Intellij, right click in your flash application in Firefox and click Debugger

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion given by Timofei & bmleite, I fixed it.

When you debug pure SWF, make sure to check the default player is a debug player.  Debug player has "Show Redraw Region" on right click.

Comment: I normally visit http://www.playerversion.com/ to find out which player version I'm running.  Note that since 10.1.??? you can also see the player version by right clicking.

Comment: HI Marty, My requirement is to test without html wrapper. So need to verify the standalone player version.

Answer (score 0):

IDEA generates html file that embeds swf file for users' convenience. If you open this html from file system, it allows you to debug SWF. If you put it (with the rest of files) to http server, then 'Debug' menu item is disabled in Chrome. In IE it works fine. This is obviously a Flash Player's bug.